# Mysql - Inverse 3 table-query

Tags: mysql, inverse

I have this query which gives me a list of firms (tblprov) with their corresponding category (tblrubro)

Both tables are related through a lookup table (tblprovxrubro)

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, r.idCat, r.rubroDesc FROM tblprov p
JOIN tblprovxrubro pr on p.id = pr.idFirm
JOIN tblrubros r on pr.idCat = r.idCat
WHERE p.id = 20
```

In this example, I have one firm related to 2 firm categories, so the query will give me this result

```
id     |  razonSocial |  idCat    |   catDesc  |
20     |    Firm 1    |     2     |Electronics |
20     |    Firm 1    |     3     | Software   |
```

What if I need to know the opposite, categories that are not related to that firm?

Cant figure it out

Comment: Decorum prohibits me from sharing my thoughts on the usefulness of providing such a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `LEFT JOIN` from the categories table to the junction table. Categories table will be the leftmost, since you want to consider all the categories. All the categories which do not have a corresponding row in the junction table for the `pid = 20` will be your required result. We consider those rows using `IS NULL` comparison operator.

```
SELECT r.idCat, r.rubroDesc 
FROM tblrubros r 
LEFT JOIN tblprovxrubro pr 
  on pr.idCat = r.idCat AND 
     pr.idFirm = 20
WHERE pr.idCat IS NULL
```